# How to dynamically load css file in Parcel bundler?

Tags: css, node.js, webpack, babeljs, parcel

I want to load RTL or LTR styles based on the user's locale.

I have tried to `import('/path/to/RTL-style.css')` but it doesn't working - the styles are not getting applied.

They will be applied only if I mention this line in the top of the file, before any code execution, in this format:

`import '/path/to/RTL-style.css'` **and without parentesis ()**

I am using Parcel bundler and babel polyfill included as the first dependency.

How to achieve what I try to do?

Comment: you can see example here :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-css-loader?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fcss-loader.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

I found it, just do this when its css file:

```
import('/colors.css').then().catch(() => {})
```

And if its js file you can do this:

```
const module = await import('/path/to/jsfile')
```